# Azure Pipeline to trigger Pipeline using YAML

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Attempting to trigger an Azure pipeline when another pipeline has been completed using a YAML. There's [documentation](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-yaml/blob/master/design/pipeline-resources.md) indicating that you can add a pipeline resource with:

```
resources:   # types: pipelines | builds | repositories | containers | packages
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: string  # identifier for the pipeline resource
    connection: string  # service connection for pipelines from other Azure DevOps organizations
    project: string # project for the source; optional for current project
    source: string  # source defintion of the pipeline
    version: string  # the pipeline run number to pick the artifact, defaults to Latest pipeline successful across all stages
    branch: string  # branch to pick the artiafct, optional; defaults to master branch
    tags: string # picks the artifacts on from the pipeline with given tag, optional; defaults to no tags
```

However, I've been unable to figure out what the "source" means. For example, I have a pipeline called `myproject.myprogram`:

```
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: myproject.myprogram
    source: XXXXXXXX
```

Moreover, it's unclear how you'd build based a trigger based on this.

I know that this can be done from the web-GUI, but it should be possible to do this from a YAML.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

For trigger of one pipeline from another azure official [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#pipeline-triggers) suggest this below solution. i.e. use **pipeline triggers**

```
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: RELEASE_PIPELINE # any arbitrary name
    source: PIPELINE_NAME.    # name of the pipeline shown on azure UI portal
    trigger:
    branches:
      include:
        - dummy_branch        # name of branch on which pipeline need to trigger
```

But actually what happens, is that it triggers two pipelines. Take an example, let suppose we have two pipelines A and B and we want to trigger B when A finishes. So in this scenario B runs 2 times, once when you do a commit (parallel with A) and second after A finishes.

To avoid this **two times pipeline run problem follow the below solution**

```
trigger: none # add this trigger value to none 
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: RELEASE_PIPELINE # any arbitrary name
    source: PIPELINE_NAME.    # name of the pipeline shown on azure UI portal
    trigger:
    branches:
      include:
        - dummy_branch        # name of branch on which pipeline need to trigger
```

By adding **trigger:none** second pipeline will not trigger at start commit and only trigger when first finish its job.

Hope it will help.

Comment: This is a better answer.  Thanks for adding it!

Comment: If your pipeline name includes spaces (e. g. My special build) then use: `- pipeline: WhatEverYouWant` and `source: My special build`
With quotations `"` everything seems to be good, but the trigger worked for me only when I removed them.

Comment: Can we pass some parameters to second pipeline?

Comment: Is the indentation for `branches` incorrect in these examples? Should `branches` be under the `trigger` key?

Comment: This did not work for me. The pipeline did not trigger on code change which is good but it did not trigger after the completion of the source pipeline.

Comment: Also doesn't work for me either when I test from a features/* branch. When I comment out #trigger: none, then both my CI-CD pipeline gets triggered. But I don't want this. I want to have CI pipeline be completed successfully first and then the CD can start. But this YAML code here doesn't trigger my CD pipeline.

Comment: I have made it work. When testing out from a features/* branch, it is important to set the Triggers in the old Classic UI to have the default branch be your features branch that you are currently testing your YAML pipelines from.

Answer (score 18):

Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#pipeline-triggers-1) says that YAML is the preferred approach. So, instead of going for the build-trigger option let's understand the, little bit confusing, YAML trigger. The following tags will work from the original question and now with a bit easier documentation:

```
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: aUniqueNameHereForLocalReferenceCanBeAnything
    project: projectNameNOTtheGUID
    source: nameOfTheOtherPipelineNotTheDefinitionId
    trigger:
      branches:
        include:
        - master
        - AnyOtherBranch
```

The documentation from Microsoft is confusing and the IDs are numerous. At times they want the Project GUID at times the project name. At times they want the pipeline name and at times the pipeline definition Id. But they use the same name for the variable (project and pipeline). And on top of that they write documentation that does not make it easy to guess which one to use the best way is to trial and error.

I think to avoid the confusion in other places I'm giving example of another place in the pipeline you refer to the same variables with different values. In the DownloadArtifact task, you need to use the project GUID and the pipeline definition Id as shown below:

```
- task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
      inputs:
        source: specific (a literal constant value not the pipeline name)
        project: projectGUIDNOTtheProjectName
        pipeline: numericDefinitionIdOfPipelineNotPipelineNameOrUniqueRef
        runVersion: 'latest'
```

Just look at how they used the same variables in a different way, but both referring to a pipeline and in my case the same exact pipeline. That could create confusion and to avoid stumbling into the next issue I give it here for clarification.

Comment: Your first yaml snippet is what really helped me. I kept thinking that the documentation meant to put a code path and not the pipeline name within DevOps. The Microsoft document does a really bad job explaining the expected values in relation to code base and DevOps.

Answer (score 15):

The resources are not for the Build Completion trigger. according to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-completion-triggers) the build completion trigger **not** yet supported in YAML syntax.

After you create the YAML pipeline you can go to the classic editor (click on `settings` or `variables`) and there create the trigger.

***Edit:***

Now you need to click on the "Triggers":

[image]

And then:

[image]

***Second Edit:***

Microsoft added this feature also the YAML :) see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#pipeline-triggers-1):

```
# this is being defined in app-ci pipeline
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: security-lib
    source: security-lib-ci
    trigger: 
      branches:
      - releases/*
      - master
```

In the above example, we have two pipelines - app-ci and security-lib-ci. We want the app-ci pipeline to run automatically every time a new version of the security library is built in master or a release branch.

Comment: It looks like there's no longer the option to edit a yaml pipeline in the classic editor. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Ash you can with the triggers options, see my edit.

Comment: I have the same issue with the same question. I do not agree with the answer that the build trigger should be used because the [documentation][1] says that yaml is to be used and these are parameters mentioned. The issue is what does the parameter documentations mean. It did not make much sense to me. Maybe someone with experience with this can explain what Microsoft mean by this excellent documentation.


  [1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#pipeline-triggers-1

Comment: The trigger is apply on the master branch only, is there a way to apply on different branch?

Comment: @TamirAdler In the YAML you specify more branches, see the example above - `releases/*`

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk I find that ADO YAML pipeline triggers don't fire for branches that have '/' forward slashes. Anyone had the same issue?

Answer (score 6):

If you're not publishing an artifact from the triggering pipeline, it won't trigger the triggered pipeline.

Also, if the `defaultBranch for manual and scheduled builds` in the triggered pipeline is not the same as your working branch, the triggered pipeline won't kick in at the end of the triggering pipeline execution.

I have created a minimum viable product for a pipeline trigger, and I explain better the two issues I just mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61398607/1198379).

Comment: You state that if you're not publishing an artifact from the triggering pipeline, it won't trigger the triggered pipeline.  That is what I thought to be true as well and am sure I read it in docs.microsoft but now I have a pipeline which we added a nightly schedule trigger and some long running tasks and conditions to prevent the publish steps so that it won't make an artifact and when it completes, its triggering the release pipeline.  Microsoft is saying that's expected behavior.  If you can point me to where you found that documented, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: As far as I remember, I didn't find it documented, that's why it took me so long to figure this out. It's possible that, in the meantime, MS has changed that, and made it work without publishing the artifact

Comment: thank you for responding.  Sounds like we are both getting some cuts on the bleeding edge of yaml pipelines :)

Comment: This answer has been really helpful for me as I wasn't getting my downstream pipeline to trigger until I started publishing an artifact (just a dummy one in my case, to make it work). So, I can confirm that this is still an issue. We're on ADO Server 2020 - perhaps people who do not find the artifact to be necessary are on a later version now?

Comment: Undervalued answer; Especially if you are working on a feature branch - invaluable!

Answer (score 1):

For my case, I was testing out my 2 YAML pipelines, CI and CD, from a features branch. Everything YAML code wise was the same as in this post, yet my CD pipeline wouldn't trigger when my CI completed in my feature branch. MS docs mention this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops

> If your pipeline completion triggers don't seem to be firing, check
> the value of the Default branch for manual and scheduled builds
> setting for the triggered pipeline. The branch filters in that
> branch's version of the pipeline are used to determine whether the
> pipeline completion trigger initiates a run of the pipeline. By
> default, Default branch for manual and scheduled builds is set to the
> default branch of the repository, but you can change it after the
> pipeline is created.

So I used the Classical UI to set my CD pipeline's default branch to my feature branch that I am currently using to create CI-CD YAML pipelines:

[image]

and set the default branch to my feature branch:

[image]

And it worked immediately. When my CI pipeline completes, the CD pipelines is automatically triggered for my features branch:

[image]

When I'm done and satisfied with my CI-CD pipelines, I will switch the default branch in Triggers back to main branch.