# Azure DevOps unable to trigger yaml pipeline off of completed build

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines-yaml

I can't get my yaml pipeline to trigger based off the build completion of another pipeline.

This is the code from the yaml pipeline I am trying to trigger to run, where `pipelineX` is the name of the pipeline build I want the run to trigger off of:

```
      resources:
        pipelines:
        - pipeline: trigger-pipeline
          source: pipelineX
          trigger: true 

      steps:
      - task: Bash@3
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |
            echo 'pipeline runs here'
```

Both pipelines are part of the same project, so that should not be an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have similar setup with my project. I am triggering 'PipelineNeedsTrigger' build based on successful build of 'PipelineTriggerFrom' pipeline. Both pipelines are under the same project. I have exported my YAML and added snippet here which might help you. I have added below trigger into my 'PipelineNeedsTrigger' which will trigger once the 'PipelineTriggerFrom' has successful build on 'master' branch. This might help you [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57304825/azure-pipeline-to-trigger-pipeline-using-yaml).

```
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: PipelineTriggerFrom
    source: PipelineTriggerFrom
    trigger:
      branches:
        include:
        - refs/heads/master
```