# Triggering an Azure Devops pipeline from another pipeline in different projects

Tags: azure-pipelines

I have 2 yml written both in different projects.

1. FirstPipeline.yml

```
# azure-pipelines.yml
name: FirstPipeline

trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- script: echo This pipeline runs first !
```

2. SecondPipeline.yml

```
 # azure-pipelines-trigger.yml
name: SecondPipeline 

trigger: none

# this pipeline will be triggered by another pipeline 
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: FirstPipeline   # Name of the pipeline resource
    source: FirstPipeline # Name of the pipeline referenced by the pipeline resource
    project: X Y Z # Required only if the source pipeline is in another project
    trigger: true # enable the trigger
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
  - script: echo This pipeline was set to be triggered after first pipeline completes.
```

But the first pipeline is not triggered when i am running second pipeline.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57304825/3554391

Answer (score 0):

Updated the second pipeline with the below code :

## azure-pipelines-trigger.yml

name: SecondPipeline

trigger: none

## this pipeline will be triggered by another pipeline

resources:
pipelines:

- pipeline: 'FirstPipeline'   # Name of the pipeline resource
  source: 'FirstPipeline' # Name of the pipeline referenced by the pipeline resource
  project: 'X Y Z' # Required only if the source pipeline is in another project
  trigger: true # enable the trigger
  pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:

- script: echo This pipeline was set to be triggered after first pipeline completes.