# Azure DevOps Pipeline trigger on a branch but only on direct commits

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to configure a Pipeline to trigger only if there is a direct commit and not through a PR (on the same branch)

The origin of this problem is that I have 2 Pipelines:

1- Manual trigger set an App version so modifies the master branch with this new version

2- The second one fires because the change and compiles with the version stamp and generates the build

3- If I create a PR to master this second Pipeline is also firing -> I don't want this

I've tried this but It didn't work as expected:

```
trigger:
  - master
pr: none
```

Any idea?

Comment: Finally I took another approach as exposed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57304825/azure-pipeline-to-trigger-pipeline-using-yaml

Comment: Hi, can you share more details about how you use the approach to solve your issue? From the link you shared it seems talking about trigger one pipeline from another pipeline.

Comment: Hi, I just did it

Comment: Thanks for sharing the answer! Now I understand that you trigger the second Pipeline from the first one and the second pipeline will not be triggered by a PR.

Answer (score 0):

`pr: none` does not work with Azure DevOps Repos: [pr definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/pr?view=azure-pipelines#implementations)

> YAML PR triggers are supported only in GitHub and Bitbucket Cloud. If
> you use Azure Repos Git, you can configure a branch policy for build
> validation to trigger your build pipeline for validation.

Check [Build validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#build-validation) for the master branch. It should not contain validations for the second pipeline.

To skip a job in your build after pr completion, you may use jobs conditions:

```
trigger:
- master

jobs:
  - job: A
    condition: ne(contains(variables['Build.SourceVersionMessage'], 'Merged PR'), True)
    steps:
      - task: CmdLine@2
        inputs:
          script: |
            echo Write your commands here
            
            echo Hello world
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I don't have a build validation for the second pipeline, I have a 3rd pipeline on build validation.

Comment: Also the build validation triggers when the PR is created, the problem is when the PR is merged adding a new commit over master

Comment: @Santiago we can not skip builds after PR commit. However, each PR commit contains `Merged PR` message. You may use it in job condition. I`ll update my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I understand that is not possible, I think this solution doesn't solves my original problem because I don't want  the pipeline to even been fired. I think I need to look for another way to achieve this. I don't know if is ok to mark this as solution

Answer (score 0):

Just as a brainstorming )) You may use an orchestration pipeline that triggers on each commit and decides which pipeline to start.

```
trigger:
- master

steps:
- task: Powershell to start the needed pipeline
  condition: ne(contains(variables['Build.SourceVersionMessage'], 'Merged PR'), True)
```

How to queue a new build: [QueueBuildWithVars.ps1](https://github.com/ashamrai/AzureDevOpsExtensions/blob/master/CustomPSTasks/QueueBuildWithVars.ps1)

Comment: I think this condition way will work, but you will get a lot of aborted pipelines on your dashboard, I'll write what I finally did

Answer (score 0):

What I finnaly did is to trigger the second Pipeline from the first one

First pipeline, sets new code version

```
trigger: none

resources:
- repo: self

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- checkout: self
  persistCredentials: true

- script: |
    git config --global user.email $BUILD_REQUESTEDFOREMAIL
    git config --global user.name "$BUILD_REQUESTEDFOR"
    // do whatever change to your code you want
    git commit -a -m "My product new version"
    git tag v$(Version)
    git push origin HEAD:$(Build.SourceBranch)
    git push --tags origin
  displayName: 'Update Version'

- script: |
    cd $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
    echo "dummy" > dummy.txt
  displayName: 'Dummy artifact'

- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  inputs:
    targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)' 
    artifactName: 'Dummy'
    publishLocation: 'pipeline'
```

The dummy task is because the second pipeline wasn't firing without an artefact published on the first one

The second pipeline starts with:

```
trigger: none

resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: NewProdVersion -> internal name, not important
    source: Production Start  -> the name of the first Pipeline
    trigger:
      branches:
        - master
        - fixes/*

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
```